# Как убрать из строки \t?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например,

`a = 'My\t\t\tname\t\tis...'`

должно стать

```
'My name is...'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используй метод *replace()*, который заменит все табуляции на пробелы:

```
a = a.replace("\t", " ")
```

более подробно про этот метод можешь почитать [здесь](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm).

А еще то же самое можно сделать с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
import re
s = "The \t fox jumped \t over  \t the log."
s = re.sub("\s+", " ", s)
print s
```

Comment: `a = a.replace("\t", " ")` - 3 пробела подряд получится

Comment: @slippyk верно, но в вопросе не было сказано, убрать или не убирать повторяющиеся \t, а в итоговой строке не понятно, сколько у автора пробелов. И я в ответе написал, что просто меняет все табы на пробелы, что говорит о точном количественном совпадении. Я предоставил альтернативы, а автор вопроса уже сам решит, что ему больше подходит =)

Comment: a =  a.replace(r"\t+", " ")  # 1, или более \t подряд станут пробелом.

Answer (score 2):

Очень простое и, ИМХО, элегантное решение:

```
' '.join(a.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 'My\t\t\tname\t\tis...'.split('\t')
' '.join([i for i in x if i != ''])
```

Comment: прошу прощения, по ошибке исправил

Answer (score 0):

```
' '.join(filter(bool, a.split('\t')))
```